# Find the probability that A,B,C are connected

Tags: probability

I was given the following problem as a homework assignment:

> Denote with $S$ the ball with center $O$. Three points $A, B$ and $C$ are chosen at random on its surface, their positions being independent and each
>   uniformly distributed on the surface. Points A and B can be connected
>   together if the angle $AOB<\pi/2$. What is the probability that they can be connected (with, for example, $A$ connecting with $B$ via $C$ if necessary)?

I was given the answer by my professor as a hint: $(\pi+2)/(4\pi)$.

I thought about it in the following way. Let $r$ denote the line that passes through the center $O$, which will intersect the ball at a point, call it $A$. Now, take a plane perpendicular to $r$ and make it pass through $O$. The plane divides the sphere into $2$ hemispheres, one that contains the point $A$ and one that does not. If $B$ is placed in the hemisphere that contains $A$, then  $AOB<\pi/2$ and so they can connect. Otherwise, they cannot. So the probability of $A$ connecting with $B$ is equivalent to the prbability that $B$ falls in one of the two hemispheres that contains $A$ which is $1/2$. (The idea of this reasonsing is to keep $A$ fixed and set it at the "center" of the hemisphere's surface). Now I am left with calculating the probability that $B$ is placed on the other hemisphere so that $A$ must connect with $B$ through $C$. Which is again $1/2$? What is wrong with this reasoning? And how would one solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please use the self-study tag when asking questions about assignments / textbook cases.

Comment: The reasoning is good until the end: guessing that a value is $1/2$ is not reasoning--it's just a guess.  In fact, when $B$ is far from $A,$ the point $C$ is constrained to lie within a narrow lune.  You have to integrate the relative area of that lune as $B$ varies; the answer must be substantially less than $1/2.$  Perhaps a more helpful hint is that the answer is $1/2(1/2 + 1/\pi).$